# Deploying docker container on a host in local network

Tags: docker, networking

I am looking for a workflow of deploying apps using docker on multiple (~5)  pi's in a local network that does not have internet connection. I researched docker-machine and swarm, but did not find  this yet.
- Is it possible to build an image on PC_A and deploy containers from it to machines  on a local network(does not have internet access)?
- What setup would I need?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. Using just Docker (without any orchestration tool like Swarm), you need to distribute the image to the other machines somewhat. You have two choices:

1. Using a [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). As you are not connected to Internet, you will need to deploy it in a machine inside the network (check [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)). When you build the image, you have to [push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/) it to your registry, and then, [pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) it from the target machines.
2. [Saving image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) to a `tar` archive and [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it, by hand, in the other machines.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This still requires me to SSH into all of them right?  is there a way to skip this? Because i should be thinking about eventually scaling up to 10s or 100s of machines.